# Google Sheet Query returns first 3 rows in one row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have made a simple query that combines data from 4 separate sheets:

```
=query({'1.MA'!A13:O200;'2.PF'!A13:O200;'3.BM'!A13:O200;'4.C'!A13:O200},"Select * where Col2 is not null ")
```

The objective is to have all data in the sheets where Column B is filled in. This works for the majority, except for the first 3 rows in the first sheet. The query returns them combined in one row.

All sheets are exactly the same, the error does not reproduce n the first 3 rows of the other sheets.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your post? It's not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

- try like this:

  ```
  =QUERY({'1.MA'!A13:O200; '2.PF'!A13:O200; '3.BM'!A13:O200; '4.C'!A13:O200},
   "select * where Col2 is not null", 0)
  ```
- or like this:

  ```
  =QUERY({'1.MA'!A13:O200; '2.PF'!A13:O200; '3.BM'!A13:O200; '4.C'!A13:O200},
   "select * where Col2 is not null", -1)
  ```
- or perhaps like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
   '1.MA'!A13:O200; '2.PF'!A13:O200; '3.BM'!A13:O200; '4.C'!A13:O200}),
   "select * where Col2 is not null", 0))
  ```